# Would non-parametric functional neural networks be possible?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, machine-learning, computational-mathematics, neural-networks

Most neural networks have activation functions which are sigmoids and then are simply linear combinations (from previous layers of outputs coming from other linear combination of sigmoids outputs and so on...).

Often one has an explicit algebraic / analytic function and it's derivative ready for calculation. But what if instead of altering a coefficient we would alter the function itself? So what is unique for each neuron is not a linear weight (on it's axions insulation), strengthening or weakening the signal to the next layer, but instead it is the very function that works on linear combinations on it's input sensors (dendrites).

**Expressed with equations**: Instead of keeping $\sigma_k \forall k$ static and optimizing wrt ${\bf W_k}, \forall k$ in
$$\min_{{\bf W_k}}\|\sigma_n({\bf W_{n}}\cdots\sigma_2({\bf W_2}\sigma_1({\bf W_1v}))\cdots) - gt\|$$
We optimize wrt to $\sigma_k, \forall k$ instead.
$$\min_{\sigma_k}\|\sigma_n({\bf W_{n}}\cdots\sigma_2({\bf W_2}\sigma_1({\bf W_1v}))\cdots) - gt\|$$

---

Since the field of neural networks is quite mature, having existed for over $50$ years and been very active since at least the $1980$s, I am very open for references to published works.

Comment: Without parameters it's not clear how one would go about optimizing since gradient descent is no longer available. If you can come up with a usable alternative that would be great.

Comment: Maybe we can interpret the function and it's derivatives ($\sigma(x),\sigma'(x)$) values as parameters in some sense (not completely free parameters of course, as we should require some regularity)?

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, you want find a way to optimize the transfer function instead of optimizing weight values?

Comment: @ThePirateBay yes, I am wondering if it could be useful and practical to do so in some way (and how to do it if that is the case).

Comment: It is proven that every real function can be represented as a neural network. Therefore, optimizing a function would mean optimizing another (some internal) neural network, and therefore it will just make it more complicated and slower. That's my point of view, I may be wrong.

Comment: Yes you may be right that it would be more complicated and require more storage or whatnot to represent these very general functions than to just store the matrices in a normal neural network, but I am kind of curious of what those pressed functions behaviour would look like. You won't get a diamond from gently polishing some dirty charcoal, you need to apply some pressure...

Comment: Probably you're more likely to get the answer (or at least opinion from experienced people in that topic) on [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions) community. It seems like the people on MSE don't prefer discussable questions.

Comment: You are probably right about that. It would be a better forum for me if I asked for my own sake.

Comment: @ThePirateBay answered : any continuous function can be approximated locally uniformly by a neural network, or by polynomials, or by sampling+convolution. You can't consider "any function", you need a parametric model for it, that's the way maths work. The other answer it to consider neural networks where the training algorithm can add as many neurons and layers it needs (a very hard research problem, which as far as I know, never worked for practical applications, even if deep-learning attempts at simulating that in some sense).

Comment: @reuns : so then just pick your favorite way to represent ***any*** function to the degree of approximation you would like and then find a way to do the optimization. How hard could it be?

Comment: Do you know how to use convolution+sampling to approximate any continuous function ? The idea is that for $f$ continuous and bounded : $f(x) \approx f_n(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y) ne^{-\pi n^2 (x-y)^2}dy \approx f_{n,a}(x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f_n(\frac{k}{e^{a n^2}}) \frac{n}{e^{a n^2}}e^{-\pi n^2 (x-k)^2}$. Of course in practice we set $f_n(\frac{k}{e^{a n^2}}) = 0$ for $|k| > N$ so it is a finite sum, and $N,k,a,f_n(\frac{k}{e^{a n^2}})$ are parameters of our model.

Comment: I know some stuff, but as I said earlier this question is not for my understanding but to help people find new ideas. Yes that convolution idea could be done for example. Or optimizing for coefficients in power or Fourier series expansions or splines or interpolation of regularized vectors of function values or something else.

Comment: Look up the CMAC neural network. It's not really what you're looking for, but it's about as unconventional as I can think of.